# How can I show own order list?

Tags: django

I would like to show all orders of a single user. This Code working perfectly. But the problem Is when I do **log out** then shows the below error. Even it doesn't go to the previous page.  Now, what can I do?

***Errors:***

```
AttributeError at /
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'user_frontend_order'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'user_frontend_order'
Exception Location: C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 247, in inner
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\Business_Website',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 13 Mar 2022 18:12:22 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
D:\1_WebDevelopment\Business_Website\business_app\views.py, line 16, in index
    queryset = request.user.user_frontend_order.all() …
```

***views:***

```
def index(request):
    total_user = User.objects.count()-1
    frontend_order_list = request.user.user_frontend_order.all()


    context = {
        "total_user":total_user,
        "frontend_order_list":frontend_order_list
    }
    return render(request,'0_index.html',context)
```

***Models:***

```
class Frontend_Order(models.Model):
    USer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_frontend_order')
    Service_Type = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+ str(".") + str(self.USer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes to the previous page. The problem is that while evaluating the logic of index, there is a problem: it aims to find the `Frontend_Order` objects of the user, but `request.user` is not a `User` object, but an `AnonymousUser`. You thus should make a proper check:

```
def index(request):
    total_user = User.objects.count()-1
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        frontend_order_list = request.user.user_frontend_order.all()
    else:
        frontend_order_list = Frontend_Order.objects.none()
    
    context = {
        'total_user': total_user,
        'frontend_order_list': frontend_order_list
    }
    return render(request, '0_index.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Frontend_Order`</s> to `FrontendOrder`.